# HexDec to Char to Password Unencrypt in PHP

Tags: php, encoding, hex

Ok, so I'm trying to figure out how to go from hexadecimal encryption to string and back, but for some reason the when I encrypt, i'm not getting the same password that was passed in, but its close...weird right?  I'm sure my syntax is wrong somewhere.  Help?

Here's a link to test a little random password.  I've set 'pw' as the hexadecimal version and pass that in:   [view demo](http://opensourcetutorials.net/ajaxtutorial/password.php?pw=3274703B3B)

```
$encoded  = (string)$_GET['pw'];  
$literals = explode(' ', wordwrap($encoded, 2, ' ', 2));  
$password = '';  

for ($i = 0; $i < count($literals); $i++) {  
    $password .= chr(hexdec($literals[$i]) - $i);  
}

echo $password . '<br />';
print_r($literals) . '<br />';
$passarray = str_split($password);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($passarray);
echo '</pre>';

for($i = 0; $i < count($passarray); $i++) {
    $newpassword .= bin2hex($passarray[$i]);
}
echo $newpassword;
```

UPDATE:

.I'm actually not trying to "encrypt" for security per se...I'm actually trying to automate the creation of Dreamweaver Site Definition files and this is the "encryption" they use to semi-hide the password.  I can do this already by copying the file and inserting different usernames, but I'd like to issue and new password each time as well.  just FYI

Comment: This is not an encryption. This is just a code conversion (base 256 → base 16 and the reverse).

Comment: If you really want to encrypt something (like a password), take a look at [MCrypt](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php).

Comment: You're right...I'm actually not trying to encrypt for security per se...I'm actually trying to automate the creation of Dreamweaver Site Definition files and this is the "encryption" they use to semi-hide the password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look closer at this line:

```
$password .= chr(hexdec($literals[$i]) - $i);
```

You're decreasing the value by `$i`. So every increment, the value will be `$literals[$i] - $i`.

This is the reverse of the above:

```
$newpassword .= dechex(ord($passarray[$i]) + $i);
```

Comment: well, that part actually works.  that line decodes the hexadecimal password and prints it (see demo).  The problem is going back to hexadecimal once I have the string.

Comment: Perfect!  Did edit to add that last line in?  I must have missed it! Thanks Lek

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Lekensteyn's above for the reversal code.  In my testing it seemed dreamweaver was also expecting uppercase letters, so i added a strtoupper as shown below. I was using this code to dynamically generate dreamweaver site definition files (.ste) from a list of domains and ftp credentials.

```
function dw_encode_pw($pw='') {
    $password = '';
    $passarray = str_split($pw);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($passarray); $i++) {
        $password .= strtoupper(dechex(ord($passarray[$i]) + $i));
    }
    return $password;
}

function dw_decode_pw($pw='') {
    if (empty($pw)) {
        return false;
    }

    $encoded  = (string) $pw;
    $literals = explode(' ', wordwrap($encoded, 2, ' ', 2));
    $password = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($literals); $i++) {
        $password .= chr(hexdec($literals[$i]) - $i);
    }

    return $password;
}
```

also thanks to http://blog.affirmix.com/2008/08/28/encoded-passwords-in-ste-site-definition-files/ and http://www.matthewratzloff.com/blog/2007/04/18/decrypting-a-dreamweaver-site-definition-password/  which also explore this topic...

Hope this helps somebody else looking for this solution!

Answer (score 0):

Hexadecimal isn't an *encryption*, but an *encoding* at best (it's mostly a number base in fact). It looks like you're mixing up the base conversion, and the hexadecimal encoding of the character encoding itself.

- `hexdec` will turn 0, 1, 9, A, F, 10 into 0, 1, 9, 10, 15, 16, respectively.
- `chr` will turn the decimal number into a character (using the ASCII character encoding)
- Not sure why you're substracting `$i` in the value you got.
- On the other side, `bin2hex` effectively gives you an hexadecimal representation of a binary sequence of data (at least so that it can be printed out). It's not necessarily the opposite of `chr(hexdec(...))`.

Overall, it's not clear what kind of password protection you're trying to achieve here, since it's just encoding.